# What would I call a program that was developed specifically for a company?

Tags: programming, computing

I am looking for a word that can describe a program I developed for a company, as opposed to a program I would create for a school assignment or for fun. I've written "paid programming task" and "practical program", but it doesn't sound so good and the latter is quite ambiguous.

Comment: How are you going to use the word (or phrase)?

Comment: e.g. Last month I developed/worked on my first -blank-

Comment: You had a [commission](https://www.lexico.com/definition/commission).

Comment: *Last month I developed/worked on my first [custom-specified] **commercial application***.

Comment: I think @FumbleFingers's  "commercial application" is the right term.  Not sure why it is just a comment not a answer though :-)

Comment: @k1eran: It's only a comment because I closevoted as POB (it's just ***one possible** answer*, not ***the** answer*).

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on the sentence you're using, but there are a few ways to say what you mean.

Software used and developed within an organization is often called either in-house or proprietary software, as opposed to shrink-wrapped of off-the-shelf software.

Work done to develop software for a client is often called contract work, and is clearly distinguished from school assignments, side projects or pet projects.